# How to deploy windows base image on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Container Engine for Kubernetes (OKE)

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How to deploy windows base image on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Container Engine for Kubernetes (OKE)

Already explored OCI but unable to find anything relevant. We have one application which is using window based images and deployed on Azure AKS but we want to deploy the same application on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure.